# How can I map a user-given string to an object property at runtime?

Tags: c#, linq, parsing, console

Given this interface:

```
public interface IToken
{
    int ID { get; }
    string Name { get; }
    string Description { get; }
    string Type { get; }
    string Category { get; }
}
```

Suppose I have an `IEnumerable<IToken>` with about ~200 members, which is constructed by reading in JSON from various files. To test it, I made a ConsoleApplication project and I am trying to manipulate the collection via LINQ with decent success.

What I would like to do is receive input from the console and process it via commands I design:

```
exit
list token
list token filter [filterType] [filterValue]
```

So if I just type `list token`, it would iterate the list and output all the members. Easy.

The problem comes if I type `list token filter Category "SomeCategory"` (which should select all `IToken` objects in the collection where `Category == "SomeCategory"`); I have no idea how to program it to map a user-supplied string of `[filterType]` to an object property named `Category` (or some other property that may or may not be present on IToken), **unless I hardcode it for every case**. To me, that's too much effort and doesn't scale well.

What is the best approach to do this?

Right now, my code is:

```
private void Input_ListTokens(string filterType, string filterValue)
{
    IEnumerable<string> result = null;

    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filterType) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filterValue))
    {
        result = from t in Tokens
                    select t.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        if (filterType == "type")
            result = from t in Tokens
                        where t.Type == filterValue
                        select t.ToString();

        if (filterType == "category")
            result = from t in Tokens
                        where t.Category == filterValue
                        select t.ToString();
    }

    if (result != null)
        foreach (var item in result)
            c.WriteLine(item);
    c.WriteLine();
}
```

As you can see between the two LINQ queries, the only tangible difference is

```
where t.Type == filterValue
where t.Category == filterValue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void Input_ListTokens(string filterType, string filterValue)
{
 IEnumerable<string> result = null;
   Type t = typeof(IToken);
   PropertyInfo f = t.GetProperty(filterType);
   if (f!=null)
            result = from t in Tokens
                        where t.GetValue(t)== filterValue
                        select t.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Looking at GetProperty, you made me realize I could just chain together something like `someToken.GetType().GetProperty(filter).GetValue()...` so you get the checkmark! Of course, Sergey's answer is great too; I'll keep all these in mind in the off chance I'm in a similar situation again.

Comment: -1 will not work with filter `"category"`, does not check type of property and will fail on comparison

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection or Dynamic LINQ. Reflection approach:

```
private void Input_ListTokens(string filterType, string filterValue)
{
   var type = typeof(IToken);
   var comparison = StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;
   var property = type.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => 
      p.PropertyType == typeof(string) && p.Name.Equals(filterType, comparison));

   if (property == null)
       return;

   var result = Tokens.Where(t => 
       filterValue.Equals((string)property.GetValue(t), comparison));

   foreach (var item in result)
       Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

It searches for string properties in `IToken` type which match filter type (case-insensitive). If match found, then value of this property is compared with given filter value.

For Dynamic LINQ approach you should install [System.Linq.Dynamic](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/) package. Also note, that search will be case-sensitive

```
private void Input_ListTokens(string filterType, string filterValue)
{
    var filter = String.Format("{0} = \"{1}\"", filterType, filterValue);
    var result = Tokens.AsQueryable().Where(filter);

    foreach (var item in result)           
        Console.WriteLine(item);           
}
```

You also can build expression and compile it into lambda (you can use case-insensitive property search as above):

```
private Func<IToken, bool> CreateFilter(string filterType, string filterValue)
{
    var t = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IToken), "token");        
    var left = Expression.Property(t, typeof(IToken).GetProperty(filterType));
    var right = Expression.Constant(filterValue);
    var body = Expression.Equal(left, right);
    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<IToken, bool>>(body, t);
    return predicate.Compile();
}
```

Usage:

```
private static void Input_ListTokens(string filterType, string filterValue)
{
    Func<IToken, bool> filter = CreateFilter(filterType, filterValue);

    foreach (var item in Tokens.Where(filter))           
        Console.WriteLine(item);           
}
```